# How to stop the slider from resetting to the left side on mouse release (react-spring react-use-gesture)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-image-gallery-3-59crp

Im using `react-use-gesture` to create a horizontally draggable image slider.

So far the logic I have for dragging is

```js
set({ x: down ? mx : 0 });
```

where if the user presses down on the mouse, the slider will `translate` to the left or right depending on the `mx` movement value. Once the user lets go of the mouse, it resets back to the left side: `0`.

Relevant `react-use-gesture` docs: https://use-gesture.netlify.com/docs/state

I tried multiple attempts to prevent the resetting by replacing the `0` with `offset` from the API etc., but so far I haven't figured out the logic to prevent the reset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to use-gesture. I just played with your code. What about using offset instead of movement in useDrag?

```
const bind = useDrag(
  ({ offset: [x], direction, distance, cancel }) => {
    set({x});

    // if user drags to the right for more than 350px, reset position back to 0
    if (direction[0] === 1 && distance > 350) {
      cancel();
      console.log("Please swipe left");
    }
  }
);
```

Cancel is not working in this case. You have to set x to 0 somehow I think instead of using cancel.